# Select /*csv*/ in oracle set delimeter and enclose character

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to use the **/*csv*/** to set the output to csv in oracle. But I need to change the delimiter and enclosing character.

I don't want to insert a bunch of "||" in my query to resolve this.

Comment: Why do you need to change the delimiters? AFAIK, this is a sqlDeveloper command

Comment: I don't believe you can; you'd need to export the Query Result pane, choose format Delimited, and set the delimiter and enclosing characters. You can set defaults for those for export in the Preferences, but they don't seem to be honoured by `/*csv*/` or `/*delimited*/`.

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought the /*CSV*/ etc was oracle magic.